# Java JAX-RS 404 not found

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

For some reason I get `404` every time I try to call the service at `http://localhost:8080/{context}/v1/{name}`. I'm using TomEE 8.5 and JEE 7. And yes, I've read the other questions on stackoverflow, In case you want to declare it as duplicate of x. Since this is my first time trying jax-rs/jersey, I wasn't completely sure which dependencies to add, so I've the ones that were suggested by people here.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationRestService</servlet-name>
    <servlet class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vio.project.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ApplicationRestService</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
```

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency> 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency> 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
```

-

```
@Path("/jobs")
public class JobsApi {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public JsonObject testMethod() {
      return Json.createObjectBuilder().add("hello", "world").build();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the controller as well that you created?

Comment: Where have you defined context root? What is the URL that you are trying to hit? Please provide a Minimal verifiable code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. I did now.

Comment: try url: http://localhost:8080/{context}/v1/jobs

Answer (score 0):

You should also create some class to serve the request like:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }
}
```

And try the URL like:
http://localhost:8080/{context}/v1/hello

Comment: I answered this before Vio added JobsApi.